Swift.CancellationError when displaying a 3D model in LazyVGrid with visionOS
I encounter an issue when trying to display a 3D model in a LazyVGrid. It fails to render, and I receive the following error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Swift.CancellationError error 1.)
The problem specifically occurs when I select a favorite and then switch tabs. However, when the app starts and I navigate directly to the favorites tab, all the models are displayed correctly. I saved the favorites ones using UserDefaults, and I also tried with SwiftData, but the same issue occur.
ScrollView {
   LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 10) {
         ForEach(favoritesShoes, id: \.self) { item in
              VStack(alignment: .center) {
                   Model3D(named: item.model3DName, bundle: spatialShoesRCBundle) { phase in
                      if let model = phase.model {
                          model
                          .resizable()
                          .scaledToFit()
                          .scaleEffect(1.0)              
                      } else {
                           ProgressView()
                      }
                  }            
              }
         }
     }
}


